# How to upload all files of a directory using java spring

Tags: java, spring, server, rest-client

i have files in a directory and i want to upload all these files in client side into folder in server side. here is my controller:

```
private static ArrayList<String> listFilesforFolder(final File folder) {
    ArrayList<String> arrFile = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
        if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
            listFilesforFolder(fileEntry);
        } else {
            arrFile.add(fileEntry.getName());
        }
    }
    return arrFile;
}

@GetMapping("/scanfolder")
@ResponseBody
public static void scanFolder(String[] args) throws IOException {

    logger.info(docs);
    if (!docs.isEmpty()) {
        // how to upload that file in folder automatically to server
    }
}
```

so i can send request command from client side to server execute upload all files to different folder. I'm so appreciate if have suggestion/tutorial/article to make this.

Comment: You need to send all the files in request. Suppose if you pass only path of folder that will not work because Server does not know your client folder path.